# Не получается подключить GuzzleHttp!

Tags: php, telegram-bot, composer, telegram, guzzle

Здравствуйте! Не могу подключить вот это вот дело!

**Это главная страница (index.php)**

```
require '../php/vendor/autoload.php';

include 'TelegramBot.php';

// Получаем сообщения
$telegramApi = new TelegramBot();

$updates = $telegramApi->getUpdates();

print_r($updates);
 ?>
```

**Это то, куда ссылается *include* из первой страницы (TelegramBot.php)**

```
<?php 

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class TelegramBot
{

    protected $token = "some_token";

    protected function query($method, $params = [])
    {
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot";

        $url .= $this->token;

        $url .= "/" . $method;

        if (!empty($params)) {
            $url .= "?" . http_build_query($params);
        }

        $client = new Client([
            base_uri => $url
        ])

        $result = $client->request('GET');

        return json_decode($result->getBody());
    } 

    public function getUpdates()
    {

        $response = $this->query('getUpdates');

        return $response->result;
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {

    }

}

 ?>
```

Вот что выдает PHP:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TelegramBot.php on line 26

Пишу в **XAMPP**. Файлы с кодом находятся:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php

Папка **php** c папкой **vendor** лежат в:

> C:\xampp\php

Помогите пожалуйста!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$client = new Client([
        base_uri => $url
])` <------------ ;

Вы забыли поставить знак ";" в конце. `base_uri` нужно завернуть в кавычки `'base_uri'`.

Советую использовать текстовый редактор, который подсвечивает ошибки.

Например: *Visual Studio Code*, *Atom*, *PHPStorm*(платный) etc.

Comment: Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, все ли получилось. Возможно есть еще в чем-то проблемы